# How to pull a shapefile into R from PostGIS database (in Windows)?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, r, windows, data-frame

I'm currently working on pulling data from a PostGIS database for the first time to map in R and need some help. The database contains a shapefile of countries/regions of the world. I am able to pull the attributes into R as a table through the `dbReadTable` function from the package `RPostgreSQL`. This is great for manipulating the data (adding, merging, subsetting, etc.), but ultimately, I still need to be able to actually *map* this bad boy, so I need the data to be spatial in some way (side note: I plan on mapping with `ggplot2`, so my data needs to be suitable for that). Here's the tiny bit of code I've successfully used to pull in the data as a table/data frame:

```
#load in required libraries
library(RPostgreSQL)

#connect to database
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
DB <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "dbname", user = "user", 
                      host = "host", 
                      password = "password", port = "5432")
#pull in shapefile data
world.shp <- dbReadTable(DB, "ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces")
```

Again, I have no problems connecting to the database. That said, I need to pull the data in as a shapefile rather than as a data frame. [This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64950/working-with-postgis-data-in-r) seems to be what I'm looking for, but the accepted/top solution confuses me; specifically, I don't know how to tackle this bit of code to pull in the shapefile from the database:

```
require(rgdal)
dsn="PG:dbname='gis'"
```

Similarly, I've found various solutions for Ubuntu, but only [this one](https://geospatial.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2014/01/14/load-postgis-geometries-in-r-without-rgdal/) for Windows, which spits out errors for me.

Comment: Databases like PostgreSQL do not store shapefiles for geometry operation -- they store tables, with a geometry type column.  Once loaded, the relationship between the two is severed. Most GIS software can plot geometries directly from PostgreSQL.

Comment: So there's no way to bring the shapefile into R? I've done it in QGIS, but I'm trying to do all of my mapping for this project in R.

Comment: It's ***not*** a *shapefile*.  You should be researching how to get a PostGIS **table** into R, or how to **generate** a shapefile in R from a table.  If you think about the problem as pulling a shapefile through the database then you won't be using the right search terms.

Comment: `rdal` is normally the best way to read from database sources, but the optional driver for PostgreSQL is often not compiled (e.g. in Windows); see `ogrDrivers()` if it is listed, or not. You could write shapefiles from the database, which can be read with `rgdal`.

Comment: @Vince, thanks for the clarification. I'm clearly new to PostGIS. Because I was able to pull it straight from the database into QGIS, I assumed that it was still considered a shapefile. I suppose I should ask a new updated question?

Comment: @MikeT any more advice for how to go about doing that?

Answer (score 5):

At the University of Florida, David Bucklin and I have released a [rpostgis](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rpostgis) package that provides bi-directional transfer between PostGIS and R for vector and raster data. The package does not rely on GDAL (and rgdal), and should be platform independent.

Given that you already have a functional connection `DB` established through `RPostgreSQL`, you can import PostGIS raster data type into R using the function `pgGetGeom`, for instance:

```
library(rpostgis)
world.shp <- pgGetGeom(DB, "ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces")
```

If the table is not in the `public` schema (which would be a good idea anyway), you will need to declare it using `c("schema", "table")` instead. The function assumes that the geometries are stored in the column `"geom"` by default, but you can change that with the argument `geom`.